# Why is transferring a file over LAN so slow?

Tags: windows-10, networking, lan, speed

I have two Windows 10 machines. Both are connected via cable to a hub. The switches are connected by cable and one hub is connected with the router for internet via cable (so no WiFi involved).

The internet connection for both machines is as fast as our provider allows (100Mbit/s download speed). The cables are 10000 Mbit/s CAT 7.

I shared using Windows 10 a local folder to all users of the network. The other machine can access it to put files into that folder. Unfortunately, the speed is very slow: Only 3MB/s. I assumed the copy speed being only limited by the writing speed of my hard drive which is of course much higher.

Can you explain why the speed is so slow and what to do to speed it up?

**Edit**: Here is my setup:

[image]

- H1: Fritz!Box 3272 simply used as hub/switch
- H2: TL-SG1005D
- M1: Windows 10 machine 1
- M2: Windows 10 machine 2
- P: Printer
- R: EasyBox 804 for internet access

The cable between H1 and H2 is cat7 and the cable between H2 and R as well. The cable between H1 and M1 and the cable between H2 and M2 might not by cat7 but using these cables with the shown setup I get an internet speed of at least 100Mbit/s. So I would expect to have at least this speed for local file transfers.

Comment: What kind of hubs? What kind of router? What Ethernet ports are involved at every single step? The Cat7 cable means nothing if it's connected to an 100Mbps port on a 15-year-old router/switch.

Comment: @user1686 I guess the Cat7 cables are connected to at least 1000Mbit/s ports. And as mentioned in the post my internet download speed is much higher than the speed of copying one file from one to the other machine. So it is not an issure about the ports. Furthermore, the router should not be involved, right? It's something between the two machines or does it run over the router? Why would it?

Comment: The router usually isn't involved (though depending on how the two computers are connected, the router's built-in switch might be).

Comment: By any chance do you have Hyper-V or some other VM software with a "virtual switch" set up? I had a problem of atrocious network performance between LAN machines from one particular computer in the past and it turned out to be a special network set up for Hyper-v was breaking everything.

Comment: Please provide the exact make and model of all network devices involved. If possible, please create a diagram of the network structure to show how the devices are connected.

Comment: Is it hubs or switches? They are not the same.

Comment: @DanielB I edited my question and added the structure of my setup.

Comment: @Bib I posted my setup. Now you can tell me if its hubs or switches and what the difference is in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.avm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/EN/Manuals/FRITZ_Box/Manual_FRITZBox_3272.pdf

[image: picture of device]

This picture from page 8 section 2.1 clearly states LAN ports 3 & 4 are 10/100mps.  This is a bottleneck, and if you need these ports plug your printer into port 3 or 4.

M1 and H2 need to be plugged into LAN ports 1 & 2.

The TL-SG1005D seems to be ok on the surface, but I worry about the cheapness of this device.  I found it for $20, and netgear devices are usually around $40-$60 for a similar device.

Honestly I would get rid of H1 and plug everything into H2 unless there was a specific need for H1